# How do I set an mvc app to not go to a certain aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I click 'debug' [play] on my mvc in visual studio I want it to go to the root of the application,then my controller kicks in however its going directly to a .aspx page and then throwing an error. How do I get it to go to the root?

Comment: Good question this has been bugging me too. Especially when using areas because the path is always incorrect when you press F5 and you get a 404 run time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what controller starts when launching from the Project settings "Web" tab. This can be accessed by right-clicking the project root and then selecting Properties, or alternatively by pressing Alt-Enter on your keyboard. If you leave the specific page blank, it should load the root. Otherwise, you can specify the Controller to start as well (ie. ControllerName/OtherRouteText/Etc) so that it looks similar to the actual route you would like to start.

Comment: Cool okay what I did was just open this click 'Current Page' then click back to it then save and my default route worked again, cheers!